# How to check if Edge browser is installed or not.

Tags: visual-c++, browser, windows-10, microsoft-edge

How to check if Edge browser is installed or not. 
If we iterate the Registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet", we can conclude on Firefox, IE, Chrome etc. But edge will not make an entry there. 
1. Is there any registry key that can be checked to verify whether Edge is installed or not? 
2. Apart from Registry, is there any other method?

I am doing this check via C++ program.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: May I ask why you're seeking to enumerate all of the user's browsers?

Comment: This is to fix a bug in the machine...

Comment: I work on the Edge team, and would appreciate any additional information you can provide.

Comment: Hi Sampson, it is to fix bugs related to my companies products, which may interact with browsers. I am not fixing bug in Edge.

Comment: Is your company having to write browser-specific code depending on which browser the user is using during their session? I ask only to know if there is something my team can do to improve your experience.

Comment: Yes. Based on browser I need to take respective actions.

Comment: Please consider sharing the issues you're facing. You can email me directly at josamp@microsoft.com. Put "Stack Overflow" in the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is Windows 10, it has Edge (which cannot be removed). If it is not windows 10, it does not have Edge.

This applies to all forms of Windows 10 (laptops, phones, xbox etc)

Comment: There are Windows 10 editions without Edge installed, like LTSC branches.